# Force drop a database [no ifs ands or buts]

Tags: mysql, rds

I have a staging server in which I need to drop a database and re-populate it with different tables. This is normally as easy as:

```
DROP DATABASE testbd;
```

However, usually whenever I drop the staging database, there are about 100 (valid) connections to it, and I do not care about those. Is there a fool-proof method to do a `drop database` without having to figure out whether there are open transactions, or this or that?

My thought was doing something like the following conceptually:

```
# get a global lock on everything -- no one except me can do anything now
CREATE LOCK

# get all active connections and then kill them
select concat('CALL mysql.rds_kill( ',id,');') from information_schema.processlist where DB='avails';
-- run each select statement

# drop the database
DROP DATABASE testdb

# if this is required?
END LOCK
```

The above is pseudo-code but I'm basically looking for a way to be able to issue a command and the database to drop within 5 seconds in a failproof way.

Comment: Why not just drop and recreate tables individually instead of trashing the whole database? Alternatively, why not spin up a whole other database instance if you can do that in a virtualized way?

Comment: @tadman that was one idea but it takes ~30 minutes to spin up a new database instance, but the main thing here is losing the previous permissions i had.

Comment: That sounds obnoxiously slow. Maybe it's premature for your build environment, but with a Docker-type container this can be done in seconds.

Comment: You can restart mysql service.. it will kill all connections.. and then drop the db without issues.